# Should I run conduit to protect an exposed cable and comply with code?

Tags: wiring, conduit

Minnesota  code says "exposed" wire (*NM 12/2 w ground, or 14/2 w ground*), in a basement, what does that mean?

An existing wire had been run on the backside (*on the furnace room side*) of the main wooden horizontal support beam then down the wooden vertical support beam into a receptacle. I'd like to correct this, I have framed the wall correctly but not sure how to get the wire to a new receptacle between studs.

The furnace ducting on the back side of the beam doesn't allow conduit between it and the beam up into the joist space and I certainly cant drill holes in either beam.

If the ducting prevents anything getting to the wire on the back side of the beam, would I run conduit up as far as I can get it so it would be protected and not "exposed"?

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation please?

Comment: Do you have a notice of a specific code section?  (Was it cited as an NEC violation or a local ordinance?)

Comment: @Nosparks please Article 334 covers nm cable, cable running down a basement wall without cover is a violation see 334.15.C. If an inspector can see exposed cable they usually will flag it.  A little trim to cover the gap between the duct and the wall and it is no longer exposed its more like a stud bay and that is code compliant.

Comment: A **cable** is several **wires** inside a sheath.  NM is cable not wire.  If it were wire, it would not be allowed outside conduit at all!

Comment: @EdBeal I'm aware of the conditions required in 334.15 for exposed work, what I was looking for is if the inspector quoted a state or local ordinance that goes further than the just the requirements of the NEC.

Comment: @nosparksplease. In my state the inspector is supposed to cite every code violation some like this are so obvious if you want chapter snd verse they will find a half dozen more things to provide numbers for. Or that has been my experience, they get picky on a electrician that has met code and I call them on it they almost always sign off.

Answer (score 1):

Normally anything below ceiling height requires conduit or a different wiring method. I understand you can not access the wire on the wall but if an inspector can see it they will usually say something. If you could add a trim board to cover that space between the furnace and the wall it will not be exposed and you will be good to go.